# PHP multidimensional array recursion problem

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Walk array recursively and print the path of the walk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590662/walk-array-recursively-and-print-the-path-of-the-walk)

Anyone can help me on this code?

```
<?php
function buildMenuWalk(&$array, &$depth, $currentDepth = 1)
    {
        # start new level html
        $html = '';

        # walk till the depth defined on the config
        if($currentDepth > $depth)
        {
            return null;
        }

        # loop through all items in this level
        foreach($array as $key => &$value)
        {       
            # if not in area map continue
            if(!is_numeric($key))
            {
                continue;
            }

            # if no <li> has been created yet, open the <ul>
            $html .= empty( $html ) ? '<ul class="dropdown">' : ''; 

            #extract the label from this level's array, designated by $labelKey
            $label = isset( $value['areaname'] ) ? $value['areaname'] : '';

            # open an <li>
            $html .= '<li>';

            # generate url
            $url = '';
            if($currentDepth == $depth)
            {
                $url = ' href="'.

                $url .= '"';
            }

            # construct content inside the <li>
            $html .= '<a' . $url .'>' . $label . '</a>';


            # run the function again to grab children levels
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                $html .= buildMenuWalk($value, $depth, $currentDepth + 1);
            }

            # close <li>
            $html .= '</li>';
        }

        # close <ul> if was generated content on this level
        $html .= !empty( $html ) ? '</ul>' : '';

        return $html;
    }
$depth = 2;

$config['content']['map'][1]['areaname'] = 'area_1';
$config['content']['map'][1][1]['areaname'] = 'block_1';
$config['content']['map'][2]['areaname'] = 'area_2';
$config['content']['map'][2][1]['areaname'] = 'block_1';
$config['content']['map'][2][2]['areaname'] = 'bloack_2';

echo buildMenuWalk($config['content']['map'], $depth);
?>
```

If you check the code above, Im using to display a menu recursively ...

If the script identify the menu reached the depth, will display href="" inside the  tag. Inside this href I want add all parent areas on the recursion.

For example:

```
$config['content']['map'][2]['areaname'] = 'area_2';
$config['content']['map'][2][1]['areaname'] = 'block_1';
$config['content']['map'][2][2]['areaname'] = 'bloack_2';
```

When script reaches the bloack_2, I need display:

```
<a href="area_2=2&block_2=2">
```

Since its a multidimensional array and can grow to like 4-5 dimension, the output href should count all these levels. For example area_2=1&block_10=5&sub_area_1=5&section_7=8 ...

I probably need some array to store all href path during the recursion, but I cant figure how to do it.

Thanks,

PS: The script will be used to build a dropdown menu. The parent levels don't need to be linked, so print the  tag will display the child menu. The last child, will be linked, but need contain all parent params so the results can be filtered.

Link to the code running and returning values:
http://codepad.org/iyrcdfQP

Answer (score 0):

Since this function is recursively calling itself, you'll have to refer to a global variable to keep track of the previous tree.  So here is the code that'll do what I think you want it to do.  All of you have to change is the `#generate url` section.

```
# generate url
$url = '';
if($currentDepth == $depth) {
  $url = " href=area=" . $GLOBALS['area'] . "&block=$key";
} else {
  $GLOBALS['area'] = $key;
}
```

Comment: I'll post another version below.

Comment: Thank you Chris, but on that code, I can have a bigger dimension than 2. So, I need a code where it checks if currentDepth = depth and print all the path to the current element. So, if my array got 5 dimension depth, it should print on $url. dimension1=keydimension1&dimension2=keydimension2&dimension3=keydimension3 and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of that same slice of code that makes the href= a little more like what you are describing, although it doesn't really make sense to me.

```
    # generate url
    $url = '';
    if($currentDepth == $depth) {
      $url = " href=".$GLOBALS['area_name']."=".$GLOBALS['area']."&$label=$key";
    }
    else {
      $GLOBALS['area'] = $key;
      $GLOBALS['area_name'] = $label;
    }
```

Comment: Henrique, does this code fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why one would bother with recursoin and multiple dimensions in a world of 2 dimensions as the menu in a web page is!

I would go for 2 dimensions only, the first dimension is to keep all elements (without any criteria) and the second to keep infos about the element:

[image]

Check an example for yourself, you set which element to get the function displays it along with all ancestors and root elements of previous levels (as California is).

```
<?php
function buildMenuWalk($element,$menuElements)
{
    for($i=0;$i<=$element;$i++)
    {
        //for a new level go to the next line
        if(!isset($menuElements[$i]['ancestors']))
        {
            echo '<br>______________________________________</br>';
            echo '<strong>',$menuElements[$i]['label'],'</strong> | ';
        }
        //if the element is reached display it along with ancestors
        if($i==$element)
        {
            //echo all the ancestores
            foreach($menuElements[$element]['ancestors'] as $value)
            { 
                echo $menuElements[$value]['label'],' | ';
            }
            //display the element itself
                echo '<font color=red>',$menuElements[$element]['label'],' | </font>';          
        } 
    }
}

//California
$menuElements[0]=Array('url'=>'http://www.California.com','label'=>'California');
$menuElements[1]=Array('url'=>'http://www.San Diego.com','label'=>'San Diego','ancestors'=>Array(0));
$menuElements[2]=Array('url'=>'http://www.San Jose.com','label'=>'San Jose','ancestors'=>Array(0,1));
$menuElements[3]=Array('url'=>'http://www.San Francisco.com','label'=>'San Francisco','ancestors'=>Array(0,1,2));
$menuElements[4]=Array('url'=>'http://www.Fresno.com','label'=>'San Francisco','ancestors'=>Array(0,1,2,3));
$menuElements[5]=Array('url'=>'http://www.Sacramento.com','label'=>'Sacramento','ancestors'=>Array(0,1,2,3,4));

//Wyoming
$menuElements[6]=Array('url'=>'http://www.Wyoming.com','label'=>'Wyoming');
$menuElements[7]=Array('url'=>'http://www.Cheyenne.com','label'=>'Cheyenne','ancestors'=>Array(6));
$menuElements[8]=Array('url'=>'http://www.Casper.com','label'=>'Casper','ancestors'=>Array(6,7));
$menuElements[9]=Array('url'=>'http://www.Laramie.com','label'=>'Laramie','ancestors'=>Array(6,7,8));
$menuElements[10]=Array('url'=>'http://www.Gillette.com','label'=>'Gillette','ancestors'=>Array(6,7,8,9));
$menuElements[11]=Array('url'=>'http://www.Rock Springs.com','label'=>'Rock Springs','ancestors'=>Array(6,7,8,9,10));

 echo '<pre>'; 
 buildMenuWalk(9,$menuElements);

?>
```

Comment: That is not really the question, you made a function to return a single menu and I need one for dropdown menu with multiple dimensions.