# Walk array recursively and print the path of the walk

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

Can someone help me with some code or instructions on how to walk recursively an array and when reaching the last element print the full path to it? A simple echo will work because I will adapt the code to some other function I'm developing.

The function doesn't need to figure the array dimension because this param will be passed:

Example:

```
$depth = 8;

$array[1][3][5][6][9][5][8][9];
```

When function reachs the 8th element it print all the path to it:

```
//print path
'1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 9 -> 5 -> 8 -> 9'
```

- As I said, only printing in this format will work cause I will implement the code into some other function.
- array keys can have the same value. Obviously not the same value in the same sequence for the entire arary.

**Updated:**

Walk recursively function:

```
$someArray[1][2][3] = 'end';
$someArray[1][2][6] = 'end';
$someArray[1][3][6] = 'end';
$someArray[4][3][7] = 'end';

function listArrayRecursive(&$array_name, $ident = 0){
    if (is_array($array_name)){
        foreach ($array_name as $k => &$v){
            if (is_array($v)){
                for ($i=0; $i < $ident * 10; $i++){ echo "&nbsp;"; }
                echo $k . " : " . "<br>";
                listArrayRecursive($v, $ident + 1);
            }else{
                for ($i=0; $i < $ident * 10; $i++){ echo "&nbsp;"; }
                echo $k . " : " . $v . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "Variable = " . $array_name;
    }
}

listArrayRecursive($someArray);
```

Will print:

```
1 :
      2 :
                3 : end
                6 : end
      3 :
                6 : end
4 :
      3 :
                7 : end
```

Now, how can I also print the path of the array everytime it reaches the end? For example:

```
1 :
      2 :
                3 : end : path -> 1,2,3
                6 : end : path -> 1,2,6
      3 :
                6 : end : path -> 1,3,6
4 :
      3 :
                7 : end : path -> 4,3,7
```

EDITED CODE ADDING A THIRD PARAM TO RECORD THE PATH:

```
$someArray[1][2][3] = 'end';
$someArray[1][2][6] = 'end';
$someArray[1][3][6] = 'end';
$someArray[4][3][7] = 'end';
$someArray[3][2] = 'end';

function listArrayRecursive(&$array_name, $ident = 0, $path = null){
     foreach ($array_name as $k => &$v){
         if (is_array($v)){
            for ($i=0; $i < $ident * 10; $i++){ echo "&nbsp;"; }
            echo $k . " : " . "<br>";
            $path .= $k . ', ';
            listArrayRecursive($v, $ident + 1, $path);
        }else{
             for ($i=0; $i < $ident * 10; $i++){ echo "&nbsp;"; }
             echo $k . " : " . $v . ' - path -> ' . $path . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

listArrayRecursive($someArray);
```

Will print:

```
1 :
          2 :
                    3 : end - path -> 1, 2,
                    6 : end - path -> 1, 2,
          3 :
                    6 : end - path -> 1, 2, 3,
4 :
          3 :
                    7 : end - path -> 1, 4, 3,
3 :
          2 : end - path -> 1, 4, 3,
```

Comment: Well, it is basic task to solve with recursion. What have you tried?

Comment: @zerkms actually I have this code for the recursion http://codepad.org/iyrcdfQP but Im stuck on the part to tracking the path to the current $key.

Comment: Can you give a more clear example, what of multiple items within any given depths of array or if the array is not nested as deep as `$depth`? What problem is this solving?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ Yah, it will never be that depth, just trying to illustrate. When I start using the script the maximum depth I will encounter will probably be 3 levels. If you check the code on the comment above you will see what Im doing with it.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/tW52eW

Comment: Did you post this question earlier? That code looks familiar.

Comment: @salathe I posted the code and execution here: http://codepad.org/iyrcdfQP ... It will be used to print a menu and do other things. Im setting up a map array dynamically generate menus, tables, forms for me. Inside the ['map'] key the recursion should only walk numbers that is why I use is_number. All other elements going to be a setting to the level the array is. Depth would be the dimension of the array. And it will be used to print a dropdown menu with multiple dimensions. As I said on the comment above, these should have a maximum of 3 dimension ...

Comment: @Herbert Sorry, I did. Since english is not my native language, I can have issues expressing myself. As I always get answer here but did not on that question, thought I could rewrite the hole question for a better explanation ...

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ Did you done any mod on that code you reposted the URL? Could not locate. Thanks,

Comment: @Henrique Nope, it's just the same code, but I am using viper7 because that shows output as HTML instead of plaintext.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you should vote to delete the other question before this gets flag as exact duplicate.

Comment: @Herbert ok, flagged it to be deleted.

Comment: Please do not re-post the same question. If you need to re-word, then re-word the original.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could employ a `RecursiveIteratorIterator` ([docs](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator)) to take the hard work out of recursing through the arrays.

```
function listArrayRecursive($someArray) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($someArray), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {
        $indent = str_repeat('&nbsp;', 10 * $iterator->getDepth());
        // Not at end: show key only
        if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {
            echo "$indent$k :<br>";
        // At end: show key, value and path
        } else {
            for ($p = array(), $i = 0, $z = $iterator->getDepth(); $i <= $z; $i++) {
                $p[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
            }
            $path = implode(',', $p);
            echo "$indent$k : $v : path -> $path<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution but you must be careful because if your leaf is an object, `$iterator->hasChildren()` returns true and the code actually won't print the path which led to the leaf object. I found a workaround in my answer

Comment: finally found this answer to my question! But I still miss a last thing: how can I print array indexes in square brackets rather than in commas? geometry,5,obs,0,latitude  should be geometry[5]->obs[0]->latitude

Answer (score 0):

This example is to give you idea, not to solve the actual task.

```
function recursiveSearch($array,$search){
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        if($val==$search)return $key;
        $x=recursiveSearch($array[$key],$search);
        if($x)return $key.' -> '.$x;
    }
}

echo recursiveSearch($array,'search');
```

If no match is found, null is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a= array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$val = end($a);
print_array($a,$val);
function print_array(&$arr, $val)
{
    if ($val === false)
        return;

    $curr = prev($arr);
    print_array($arr,$curr);
    echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a function that makes recursive looping a bit easier:
Similar to array_walk_recursive but with some extra functionality

```
public static function walk($array, $callback, $custom = null, $recursive = false, $info = [])
{
    $r = $recursive;
    if (gettype($r) === 'integer') {
        $r--;
    }
    $info['depth'] = empty($info)?1:$info['depth'] + 1;
    $info['count'] = count($array);
    $info['i'] = 1;
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v) && $r > 0) {
            $array[$k] = static::walk($v, $callback, $custom, $r, $info);
        } else {
            $array[$k] = $callback($v, $k, $custom, $info);
        }
        $info['i'] ++;
    }
    return $array;
}

public static function walkable($v, $k, $custom, $info)
{
    if (is_string($v)) {
        return $v." [ custom: {$custom['key']} ] [ level: ".$info['depth'].' | No '.$info['i'].' of '.$info['count']." ]";
    }
    return $v;
}
```

Called like so:

```
   $result = Namespace\ClassName::walk($array, ['Namespace\ClassName', 'walkable'], ['key'=>'value'], true);
```

Setting recursive to false will only evaluate the first level.

Setting recursive to true will cause it to traverse the entire array.

Setting recursive to an integer will cause it to only traverse to that depth.

Walkable functions can be referenced or passed to callback as anonymous function.

(expects: value, key, custom, info)
The returned value replace the current value.

Custom data can be passed and some additional info is provided for you.

You can expand on the walk function if you need additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Here is a Depth-First Search-ish solution(no path depth included, it reaches until the very end of the array). Comment the 'if' statement if u don't want to include the value:

```
$output = array();
retrievePath($someArray, $output);

function retrievePath($someArray, array &$pathKeeper)
{
    if(!is_array($someArray)){ // $someArray == "end"
        $element = array_pop($pathKeeper) ?? '';// if the array is empty pop returns null, we don't want that
        array_push($pathKeeper, $element . '->'. $someArray);
    } else{
        end($someArray);//we want to get the last element from the array so we move the internal pointer to it's end
        $endElKey = key($someArray);//take the key where the pointer is
        reset($someArray);
        foreach($someArray as $key=>$value){
            $element = array_pop($pathKeeper);
            array_push($pathKeeper, $element === null ? $key : $element . '->' . $key);// we don't want '->' at the beginning
            retrievePath($value, $pathKeeper);
            if($key != $endElKey) //we check whether this is not the last loop
                array_push($pathKeeper, $element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function printListRecursive($a, $var='', $i = 0) {
    if (!is_array($a)) {
        $var .= $a;
        return $var;
    }
    $string = "";
    foreach ($a as $k => $value) {
        $string .= str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $i) .' - '. $k . ':';
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $string .= $value . '<br />';
        } else {
            $string .= '<br />';
            $string .= printListRecursive($value, $var, $i + 1);
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
$test_array = [
    'America' => [
        'Argentina' => 'Buenos Aires',
        'Peru' => 'Lima'
    ],
    'Europe' => [
        'Ireland' => 'Dublin',
        'France' => 'Paris',
        'Italy' => 'Rome'
    ]
];
$result = printListRecursive($test_array);
echo $result;
?>
```

[Check code here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0qev-phb9)

Comment: The sandbox demo is not permitted to run.  Please [edit] your answer to provide a current sandbox that works.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following function based on @salathe's one. It returns an array where each element is an array containing the leaf at index 0 and the array of the path keys at index 1:

```
function loosenMultiDimensionalArrayPathForEachVal($array) {
    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);        
    $iterator->rewind();
    $res = [];
    foreach ($iterator as $v) {
        $depth = $iterator->getDepth();
        for ($path = array(), $i = 0, $z = $depth; $i <= $z; $i++) {
            $path[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
        }
        $leaf = $array;
        foreach ($path as $pathKey) {
            $leaf = $leaf[$pathKey];
        }
        if (!is_array($leaf)) {
            $res[] = [
                $v,
                $path
            ];
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

The main reason I implemented this one is that `$iterator->hasChildren()` returns `true` if the current iterated leaf is an object. Therefore, I wouldn't be able to get the path of it that way.

Comment: Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in line xxxx

Comment: Could you post your code using this function so that I can try to replicate it?

Comment: $file_contents=file_get_contents("data.json");

    $json_dump=json_decode($file_contents); 

listArrayRecursive($json_dump);

loosenMultiDimensionalArrayPathForEachVal($json_dump);

---------------------
First call works fine, second one raises error.

Comment: Thank you for the sample. You can get the expected output by setting the second parameter `bool $assoc` (defaults to `false`) of `json_decode` to `true`, i.e.: `json_decode($file_contents, true);`. `loosenMultiDimensionalArrayPathForEachVal ` assumes you are passing it a multi-dimensional array, not an `stdClass` object. If it helped, you can upvote my answer.

Comment: in this way, it just does not print anything (but listArrayRecursive()  keeps working). It is executed, because if I put ECHO "debug" here and there it prints "debug"...  but that's all it does.

Comment: I found a solution, I added my answer.

Comment: `loosenMultiDimensionalArrayPathForEachVal` returns the array with each leaf value and path, it doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, which also keeps into account if elements of the structure are arrays:

```
$file_contents=file_get_contents("data.json");
$json_dump=json_decode($file_contents); 
printPath($json_dump, '', "" ,"");

function printPath($the_array, $path, $prevType) {
// Parse all elements of a structure 
// and print full PHP path to each one.
    foreach($the_array as $key => $value)  {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            // Array element cannot be directly printed: process its items as     objects:
            printPath($value, $path  . $key , "array");
        } else {            
            if (!is_object($value))  { // If the element is not an object, it can be printed (it's a leaf)
                if(is_string($value)) { 
                    $finalValue = '"' . $value . '"'; 
                } else { 
                    $finalValue = $value;
                }
                if($prevType == "array") {
                    // If array element, add index in square brackets
                    echo($path  . "["  . $key . "] =  " .  $finalValue . "<br>");
                } else {
                    echo($path . $key  . " = " . $finalValue . "<br>");                     
                }   

            } else { // else store partial path and iterate:
                if($prevType == "array") {
                    // Path of array element must contain element index:  
                    printPath($value, $path . "["  . $key . "]->"  , "dummy");
                } else {
                    printPath($value, $path . $key . "->", "dummy");
                }           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
status->connections->DSS-25->band = "X"
status->connections->DSS-25->endAt = "2019-11-20T20:40:00.000Z"
status->connections->DSS-25->startAt = "2019-11-20T12:40:00.000Z"
geometry[0]->obs[0]->name = "UDSC64"
geometry[0]->obs[0]->hayabusa2->azm = 90.34
geometry[0]->obs[0]->hayabusa2->alt = -20.51
```

In case anybody is interested, here it is the port to Javascript:

```
function iterate(obj, stack, prevType) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if ( Array.isArray(obj[property]) ) {
            //console.log(property , "(L="  + obj[property].length + ") is an array  with parent ", prevType, stack);
            iterate(obj[property], stack  + property , "array");
        } else {
            if ((typeof obj[property] != "string")  && (typeof obj[property] != "number"))  {
                if(prevType == "array") {
                    //console.log(stack + "["  + property + "] is an object, item of " , prevType, stack);
                    iterate(obj[property], stack + "["  +property + "]." , "object");
                } else {
                    //console.log(stack +    property  , "is " , typeof obj[property] , " with parent ", prevType, stack );
                    iterate(obj[property], stack  + property + ".", "object");
                }   
            } else {
                if(prevType == "array") {
                    console.log(stack + "["  + property + "] =  "+  obj[property]);

                } else {
                    console.log(stack +    property  , " =  " ,  obj[property] );                       
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}

iterate(object, '', "File")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a third parameter which holds the actual path as String. At the end you can output it then.

Comment: already tried that but not as simple. Check the code I just edited. Any advice?