# How to extract array Keys to String in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to extract a associative array keys into a string and implode with "/" or any character/symbols.

For eg:

```
$array = array([key1] => 
                array([key11] => 
                     array([key111] => 'value111', 
                           [key112] => 'value112', 
                           [key113] => 'value113',
                          ),
                 ),
           );
```

I need an output as below array:

```
array([0] => 'key1/key11/key111',[1] => 'key1/key11/key112', [2] => 'key1/key11/key112');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited an answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623716/1947677) and came up with the following code.

```
function listArrayRecursive($someArray, &$outputArray, $separator = "/") {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($someArray), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {

        if (!$iterator->hasChildren()) {
            for ($p = array(), $i = 0, $z = $iterator->getDepth(); $i <= $z; $i++) {
                $p[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
            }
            $path = implode($separator, $p);
            $outputArray[] = $path;
        }
    }
}

$outputArray = array();
listArrayRecursive($array, $outputArray);
print_r($outputArray);
```

**Input:**

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [key11] => Array
                (
                    [key111] => value111
                    [key112] => value113
                    [key113] => value113
                )
        )
)
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => key1/key11/key111
    [1] => key1/key11/key112
    [2] => key1/key11/key113
)
```

Comment: Why deleted your comment related to the `implode` line which I've never complained and gave me a downvote for that!? Strange kind of discussion here.

Comment: I've deleted the comment because I saw your first version was the same as my code, so you were right. And who said I've downvoted you?

Comment: Huh? My first version? The first version of my answer was same as yours? I've made my answer just 12 minutes before yours. And I can't understand your first sentence, because your comment was `My answer has this line $path = implode('/', $p); which defines the operator` and what's this related to my first version? I don't mind either way. Discussion is finished.

Comment: @rabude I'm having difficulties to explain myself. I meant in my comment that my answer let you change the separator (inside the function) and your first version did not, hence the poster's comment on your answer. But then I saw your first version also allows to change the separator, so I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Works for different depth of array:

```
function getKeys($array, $prefix='', $separator = '/') {
  $return = array();
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) $return[] = $prefix . $key;
    else $return = array_merge($return, getKeys($value, $prefix . $key . separator), $separator);
  }
  return $return;
}

$keys = getKeys($array, '', '#');
```

See online fiddle http://ideone.com/krU4Xn

Comment: Its works, But how can i change that "/" into dynamic way as using function param.

Comment: See my edit (fiddle is also modified), but this should be an easy one, if you read the manual on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: And why do you accept an other answer, that seems to be more incomprehensible for you than mine and also has no option to specify separator!?

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like...

```
    $mapArray = array();
    $symbol = '/';
    foreach($array as $k =>$v)
        foreach($v as $k1 =>$v1)
            foreach($v1 as $k2 =>$v2)
                $mapArray[] = $k.$symbol.$k1.$symbol.$k2;
```

also this obviously only works in this particular case, if it needs to be more generic it can be done, but I think this should get you started.