# Multidimensional Array Listing Printing Php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have following array with php code
I could not find where I am mistaken

I'm trying to filter some of these array results and delete them. When I try to list them I could not succeded

```
array (
  0 => 'do-update.php',
  1 => 'sitemap.xml',
  2 => 'sitemap.xml.gz',
  3 => 'wp-config.php',
  'wp-content' => 
  array (
    'uploads' => 
    array (
      2013 => 
      array (
        '05' => 
        array (
          0 => 'kabeduvarkad-1024x768.jpg',
          1 => 'kabeduvarkad-150x150.jpg',
          2 => 'kabeduvarkad-300x225.jpg',
          3 => 'kabeduvarkad-940x198.jpg',
          4 => 'kabeduvarkad.jpg',
          5 => 'kabeduvarkad1-1000x288.jpg',
          6 => 'kabeduvarkad1-1024x768.jpg',
          7 => 'kabeduvarkad1-150x150.jpg',
          8 => 'kabeduvarkad1-300x225.jpg',
          9 => 'kabeduvarkad1-400x300.jpg',
          10 => 'kabeduvarkad1.jpg',
          11 => 'kabeduvarkad2-1000x288.jpg',
          12 => 'kabeduvarkad2-1024x768.jpg',
          13 => 'kabeduvarkad2-150x150.jpg',
          14 => 'kabeduvarkad2-300x225.jpg',
          15 => 'kabeduvarkad2-400x300.jpg',
          16 => 'kabeduvarkad2.jpg',
        ),
        10 => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      2014 => 
      array (
        '02' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'wp-update' => 
  array (
    0 => 'wp-update.tar',
    1 => 'wp-update.tar.gz',
    2 => 'wp-update1.tar',
    3 => 'wp-update1.tar.gz',
  ),
  4 => 'wp-update.tar.gz',
)
```

This is my function

```
function listArrayRecursive($array_name, $ident = ''){
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array_name as $k => $v){
        if (is_array($v)){
            $result[] = listArrayRecursive($v, $ident.'/'.$k);
        }else{
            $result[] = $ident. '/' . $v . '<br>';
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I have following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => /do-update.php<br>
    [1] => /sitemap.xml<br>
    [2] => /sitemap.xml.gz<br>
    [3] => /wp-config.php<br>
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-1024x768.jpg<br>
                                    [1] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-150x150.jpg<br>
                                    [2] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-300x225.jpg<br>
                                    [3] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-940x198.jpg<br>
                                    [4] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad.jpg<br>
                                    [5] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-1000x288.jpg<br>
                                    [6] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-1024x768.jpg<br>
                                    [7] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-150x150.jpg<br>
                                    [8] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-300x225.jpg<br>
                                    [9] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-400x300.jpg<br>
                                    [10] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1.jpg<br>
                                    [11] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad2-1000x288.jpg<br>
                                    [12] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad2-1024x768.jpg<br>
                                    [13] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad2-150x150.jpg<br>
                                    [14] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad2-300x225.jpg<br>
                                    [15] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad2-400x300.jpg<br>
                                    [16] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad2.jpg<br>
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => /wp-update/wp-update.tar<br>
            [1] => /wp-update/wp-update.tar.gz<br>
            [2] => /wp-update/wp-update1.tar<br>
            [3] => /wp-update/wp-update1.tar.gz<br>
        )

    [6] => /wp-update.tar.gz<br>
)
```

Expected Result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => /do-update.php<br>
    [1] => /sitemap.xml<br>
    [2] => /sitemap.xml.gz<br>
    [3] => /wp-config.php<br>
    [4] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-1024x768.jpg<br>
    [5] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-150x150.jpg<br>
    [6] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-300x225.jpg<br>
    [7] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-940x198.jpg<br>
    [8] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad.jpg<br>
    [9] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-1000x288.jpg<br>
    [10] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-1024x768.jpg<br>
    [11] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-150x150.jpg<br>
    [12] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-300x225.jpg<br>
    [13] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1-400x300.jpg<br>
    [14] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad1.jpg<br>
    ...
    [110] => /wp-update/wp-update.tar<br>
    [111] => /wp-update/wp-update.tar.gz<br>
    [112] => /wp-update/wp-update1.tar<br>
    [113] => /wp-update/wp-update1.tar.gz<br>
    [114] => /wp-update.tar.gz<br>
)
```

Comment: where is the code you tried to achieve this?

Comment: I updated for better view

Comment: Change `$result[] = listArrayRecursive($v, $ident.'/'.$k);` to `$result = array_merge($result, listArrayRecursive($v, $ident.'/'.$k));`

Comment: Are there better solution than array_merge

Comment: @DenizPorsuk What is wrong with array_merge? And why the downvotes? My Answer explains what the problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590662/walk-array-recursively-and-print-the-path-of-the-walk this might help you

Comment: @DenizPorsuk You have three answers. All are at least valid. Consider accepting the one that best solved this very basic problem for you and also consider upvoting answers to show your appreciation for people effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With `$var[] =`  you basically say that you want to add a new Element to `$var` with an incremented key.
Your Recursive frunction returns an array.
So this array is assigned as a new element in your array.
But what you want is a flat array.

Instead of adding an array to your array like this:

```
if (is_array($v)){
    $result[] = listArrayRecursive($v, $ident.'/'.$k);
```

[Merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) the existing arrays like this:

```
if (is_array($v)){
    $tmpResult = listArrayRecursive($v, $ident.'/'.$k);
    $result    = array_merge($result, $tmpResult);
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation @Andresch Serh . Are there any way to add directly without incremented key

Comment: Thou i fail to see why you would want that without further explaining from you, what you could do as well is temporarily store your result from the recursive call and iterate over that result, adding it to your result. But that would simply reengineer what array_merge does already.
I fail to see why you would want that.

Comment: @DenizPorsuk The problem was that array_merge doesn't except functions as arguments. Now it works with my edit. I also edited an eval.in link where you can see the running solution. https://eval.in/143299

Answer (score 0):

Ok use this function its working

```
$all=array();
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)); 
 foreach($it as $v) { 
   $all[]=$v;
 } 
print_r($all);
```

Comment: This gives me `Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /tmp/execpad-5f5bf77b1210/source-5f5bf77b1210 on line 56
NULL` here: https://eval.in/143244

Comment: I like this solution also. Where can I learn more information about RecursiveIterators

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

// Dummy data source
$data = array(
    '/do-update.php',
    '/sitemap.xml',
    '/sitemap.xml.gz',
    '/wp-config.php',
    array(
        array(
            array(
                '/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-1024x768.jpg',
                '/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-150x150.jpg',
                '/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-300x225.jpg<br>'
            )
        )
    )
);

// Helper function
function getFiles($data, &$fileList) {
    foreach ($data as $dataItem) {
        if (is_array($dataItem))
            getFiles($dataItem, $fileList);
        else
            $fileList[] = $dataItem;
    }
}

// Debug
echo "<b>Orignal Array</b>";
var_dump($data);
echo "<hr>";

// Helper function usage
echo "<b>Parsed Array</b>";
$fileList = array();
getFiles($data, $fileList);
var_dump($fileList);

?>
```

Output:

[image]