# Convert nested JSON from URL response to flat JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Whhat I am trying to achieve is to flatten a JSON nested response directly on the fly. The response I am getting from the API URL is

```
 {   "currency" : "USD",   "results" : [ {
 "itineraries" : [ {
   "outbound" : {
     "duration" : "17:50",
     "flights" : [ {
       "departs_at" : "2018-10-15T08:45",
       "arrives_at" : "2018-10-15T11:00",
       "origin" : {
         "airport" : "IST",
         "terminal" : "I"
       },
       "destination" : {
        "airport" : "LHR",
        "terminal" : "5"
      },
      "marketing_airline" : "BA",
      "operating_airline" : "BA",
      "flight_number" : "675",
      "aircraft" : "320",
      "booking_info" : {
        "travel_class" : "ECONOMY",
        "booking_code" : "S",
        "seats_remaining" : 7
      }
    }, {
      "departs_at" : "2018-10-15T16:55",
      "arrives_at" : "2018-10-15T19:35",
      "origin" : {
        "airport" : "LHR",
        "terminal" : "5"
      },
      "destination" : {
        "airport" : "BOS",
        "terminal" : "E"
      },
      "marketing_airline" : "BA",
      "operating_airline" : "BA",
      "flight_number" : "203",
      "aircraft" : "777",
      "booking_info" : {
        "travel_class" : "ECONOMY",
        "booking_code" : "N",
        "seats_remaining" : 9
      }
    } ]
  },
  "inbound" : {
    "duration" : "14:00",
    "flights" : [ {
      "departs_at" : "2018-10-21T19:25",
      "arrives_at" : "2018-10-22T07:00",
      "origin" : {
        "airport" : "BOS",
        "terminal" : "E"
      },
      "destination" : {
        "airport" : "LHR",
        "terminal" : "5"
      },
      "marketing_airline" : "BA",
      "operating_airline" : "BA",
      "flight_number" : "212",
      "aircraft" : "388",
      "booking_info" : {
        "travel_class" : "ECONOMY",
        "booking_code" : "N",
        "seats_remaining" : 9
      }
    }, {
      "departs_at" : "2018-10-22T10:25",
      "arrives_at" : "2018-10-22T16:25",
      "origin" : {
        "airport" : "LHR",
        "terminal" : "5"
      },
      "destination" : {
        "airport" : "IST",
        "terminal" : "I"
      },
      "marketing_airline" : "BA",
      "operating_airline" : "BA",
      "flight_number" : "676",
      "aircraft" : "320",
      "booking_info" : {
        "travel_class" : "ECONOMY",
        "booking_code" : "S",
        "seats_remaining" : 9
      }
    } ]
  }
} ],
"fare" : {
  "total_price" : "486.17",
  "price_per_adult" : {
    "total_fare" : "486.17",
    "tax" : "343.17"
  },
  "restrictions" : {
    "refundable" : false,
    "change_penalties" : true
  }
}   }, {
"itineraries" : [ {
  "outbound" : {
    "duration" : "10:55",
    "flights" : [ {
      "departs_at" : "2018-10-15T14:35",
      "arrives_at" : "2018-10-15T18:30",
      "origin" : {
        "airport" : "IST",
        "terminal" : "I"
      },
      "destination" : {
        "airport" : "BOS",
        "terminal" : "E"
      },
      "marketing_airline" : "TK",
      "operating_airline" : "TK",
      "flight_number" : "81",
      "aircraft" : "333",
      "booking_info" : {
        "travel_class" : "ECONOMY",
        "booking_code" : "W",
        "seats_remaining" : 9
      }
    } ]
  },
  "inbound" : {
    "duration" : "09:35",
    "flights" : [ {
      "departs_at" : "2018-10-21T23:35",
      "arrives_at" : "2018-10-22T16:10",
      "origin" : {
        "airport" : "BOS",
        "terminal" : "E"
      },
      "destination" : {
        "airport" : "IST",
        "terminal" : "I"
      },
      "marketing_airline" : "TK",
      "operating_airline" : "TK",
      "flight_number" : "82",
      "aircraft" : "333",
      "booking_info" : {
        "travel_class" : "ECONOMY",
        "booking_code" : "W",
        "seats_remaining" : 9
      }
    } ]
  }
} ],
"fare" : {
  "total_price" : "528.31",
  "price_per_adult" : {
    "total_fare" : "528.31",
    "tax" : "344.31"
  },
  "restrictions" : {
    "refundable" : false,
    "change_penalties" : true
  }
}   } ] }
```

And what I basically need is to get it formatted in a flat way, so everything is on the same level.

I am getting the response file_get_content like this
$json_url = file_get_contents('https ://domain/api');
And if I print it it works fine, but having troubles simplifying the result to a flat JSON Response.

**EDIT**
Something like

```
 {
    "currency": "USD",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.duration": "17:50",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].departs_at": "2018-10-15T08:45",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].arrives_at": "2018-10-15T11:00",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].origin.airport": "IST",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].origin.terminal": "I",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].destination.airport": "LHR",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].destination.terminal": "5",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].marketing_airline": "BA",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].operating_airline": "BA",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].flight_number": "675",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].aircraft": "320",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].booking_info.travel_class": "ECONOMY",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].booking_info.booking_code": "S",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].booking_info.seats_remaining": 7,
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].departs_at": "2018-10-15T16:55",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].arrives_at": "2018-10-15T19:35",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].origin.airport": "LHR",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].origin.terminal": "5",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].destination.airport": "BOS",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].destination.terminal": "E",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].marketing_airline": "BA",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].operating_airline": "BA",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].flight_number": "203",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].aircraft": "777",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].booking_info.travel_class": "ECONOMY",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].booking_info.booking_code": "N",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[1].booking_info.seats_remaining": 9,
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.duration": "14:00",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].departs_at": "2018-10-21T19:25",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].arrives_at": "2018-10-22T07:00",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].origin.airport": "BOS",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].origin.terminal": "E",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].destination.airport": "LHR",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].destination.terminal": "5",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].marketing_airline": "BA",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].operating_airline": "BA",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].flight_number": "212",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].aircraft": "388",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].booking_info.travel_class": "ECONOMY",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].booking_info.booking_code": "N",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].booking_info.seats_remaining": 9,
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].departs_at": "2018-10-22T10:25",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].arrives_at": "2018-10-22T16:25",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].origin.airport": "LHR",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].origin.terminal": "5",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].destination.airport": "IST",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].destination.terminal": "I",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].marketing_airline": "BA",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].operating_airline": "BA",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].flight_number": "676",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].aircraft": "320",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].booking_info.travel_class": "ECONOMY",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].booking_info.booking_code": "S",
    "results[0].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[1].booking_info.seats_remaining": 9,
    "results[0].fare.total_price": "486.17",
    "results[0].fare.price_per_adult.total_fare": "486.17",
    "results[0].fare.price_per_adult.tax": "343.17",
    "results[0].fare.restrictions.refundable": false,
    "results[0].fare.restrictions.change_penalties": true
    }
    {
    "currency": "USD",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.duration": "10:55",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].departs_at": "2018-10-15T14:35",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].arrives_at": "2018-10-15T18:30",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].origin.airport": "IST",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].origin.terminal": "I",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].destination.airport": "BOS",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].destination.terminal": "E",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].marketing_airline": "TK",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].operating_airline": "TK",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].flight_number": "81",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].aircraft": "333",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].booking_info.travel_class": "ECONOMY",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].booking_info.booking_code": "W",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].booking_info.seats_remaining": 9,
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.duration": "09:35",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].departs_at": "2018-10-21T23:35",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].arrives_at": "2018-10-22T16:10",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].origin.airport": "BOS",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].origin.terminal": "E",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].destination.airport": "IST",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].destination.terminal": "I",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].marketing_airline": "TK",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].operating_airline": "TK",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].flight_number": "82",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].aircraft": "333",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].booking_info.travel_class": "ECONOMY",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].booking_info.booking_code": "W",
    "results[1].itineraries[0].inbound.flights[0].booking_info.seats_remaining": 9,
    "results[1].fare.total_price": "528.31",
    "results[1].fare.price_per_adult.total_fare": "528.31",
    "results[1].fare.price_per_adult.tax": "344.31",
    "results[1].fare.restrictions.refundable": false,
    "results[1].fare.restrictions.change_penalties": true
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That is impossible, if you flatten the Json/array how are you going to access for example "departs_at"? And which "departs_at" is it going to respond back with?

Comment: Do you want to convert it to single dimensional array?

Comment: @Andreas yes, that's, duplicate keys will be overwritten.

Comment: Ideally, every itineraries should be an array {  
   "currency":"USD",
   "results":[  
      {  
         "itineraries":[  ],
         "fare":{  }
      },
      {  
         "itineraries":[  ],
         "fare":{  }
      }
   ]
}

Comment: To be honest I will be fine even if I can replace the [] with {}

Comment: I don't understand what or why you are trying to do it. Your original question can't be answered so either the question should be closed of you should edit it to a state that it can be answered

Comment: You are right... I wasn't very clear at what I am trying to achieve. Just added and edit to the original question with a sample of what is my aim.

Comment: Not sure I got it correct, can you have a look before I post as answer? https://3v4l.org/mSUB1

Comment: @Andreas OP want to concat keys upto value as key then assign this value to long key. `results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.duration` as key, `17:50` value.

Comment: @Smartpal, thats correct. The idea actually comes from here http://jsfiddle.net/S2hsS/

Comment: This sounds like a xy problem. Why do you want to do that? There must be a problem behind this that makes you think this is the solution. I'm quite sure whatever that problem is this is not a good solution.

Comment: Well, I need it in a such a format so I can easily add each value in js later on. Why do you think that it is not a good solution?

Comment: Why is it not easy to add the values the way it is? In my opinion it's a good structured array/json. Either way I have managed to recreate your json structure you want but it's malformed somewhere and won't json_decode. I truely hate json debugging. Do you know what is the problem with the json you posted as the expected result?

Comment: Well, long story short. I am trying to map the results of the API in a JS script that looks like this ------ exports.handler = (context, done) => {
const result = context.vars.get('api_result');
done(__.genericTemplate(result.map(r=>{
    return __.genericItem(r.itineraries.outbound.flights.origin.airport,r.itineraries.outbound.flights.destination.airport,r.itineraries.outbound.duration)
})));
};------ The problem is that it is very nested and I don't know how to map it when the "[]" appears. So, for me it will be easy just to prepare the response before mapping it in the JS

Comment: @lStoilov See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that replicates your expected json format.
I have borrowed some code from [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623716/5159168), and tweeked slightly to make it work for you, remember to give it an upvote.

I use the code from my comments to create the currency part of the array.
Then I pass each of the new subarray part to the code that backtracks the path and makes it json code.

```
$arr = json_decode($str,true);  // $str is the json
foreach($arr['results'] as $key => $res){
    $new[$key]['currency'] = $arr['currency'];
    $new[$key]['results'][] = $res;
}
foreach($new as $n){
    $json[] = listArrayRecursive($n);
}
$jsonNew = "[" . implode(",", $json) . "]"; // this is the new json formed as you want it
var_dump(json_decode($jsonNew), true); // for debug purpose test it




function listArrayRecursive($someArray) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($someArray), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $str = "{";
    foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {

        // Not at end: show key only
        if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {

        } else {
            for ($p = array(), $i = 0, $z = $iterator->getDepth(); $i <= $z; $i++) {
                $p[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
            }
            $path = implode('.', $p);
            $str .= '"' . $path . '": "' .$v . '"' . ",";
        }
    }
    $str = substr($str,0,-1); // remove trailing comma that makes json invalid
    $str .= "}\n";
    return $str;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/eRCIY

Comment: That looks already great. Just one thing. Is there a way to remove the array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (60)  and start directly from {
    ["currency"]=>
    string(3) "USD"

Comment: I mean the output to be like [ {}, {} ]

Comment: Isn't that what it is? Or are you again asking for a flat array where there is keys with the same name? It will not work! Trust me.

Comment: If you look at this: https://3v4l.org/9iGZD each $json element is `{ }` and they are imploded with a comma. `{ },{ }` then the concatenat makes it  `[{ },{ }]`

Comment: Maybe I am not converting it back to valid JSON then. Look at this https://3v4l.org/W9cCQ . Everything looks good except that there is --- array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4056) "{  --- in front of each array and no comma between the two
  arrays

Comment: Why do you Json encode there? What is the point? And obviously there is no comma between the arrays since the code implodes with comma later. Adding a comma in the array just makes it harder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177431/discussion-between-lstoilov-and-andreas).